# How to play sound and music in slick2D java gaming library?

Tags: java, slick2d

I am developing a 2D game in java slick2D.

The game works fine and there are no errors. But not if I try to play sound and music.

Anyway I was not able to play.

Here is my code:

```
 @Override
        public void init(GameContainer gc,StateBasedGame sbg) throws SlickException{
            sound=new Sound("sounds/town.wav");
            sound.play(1f, 1f);
            sound.play();
        }
```

And I have used jogg-0.0.7.jar, jorbis-0.0.17-1.jar, jorbis-0.0.15-1.jar.

There are no any errors but the sound is not playing.

Can you please give me a solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am posting this for others who looking for a answer for this situation.
in windows : i just changed the library location to outside the project. then it worked after resetting the library path from project properties.but in linux it worked fine without doing anything. i suggest you to change your library location to outside the project if you are sure you have added all the libraries correctly and getting some errors.

Answer (score 1):

Your project seems to be setup right since there is no exception.

I recommend to check whether your sound is really been played:

```
sound.play()
if(sound.playing){
System.print.out("works");
}
```

If this prints out "works" your .wav file might be corrupted.
You could try to use an .ogg file instead.
Furthemore I think Slick only supports  8/16bit mono/stereo format.

Another Thing you could try is to put your Code into the update Loop and see how it behaves.

Also see the documentation here: http://slick.ninjacave.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/Sound.html

```
public Sound(java.lang.String ref) throws SlickException

Parameters:ref - The location of the OGG or MOD/XM to load
```

Apparently the constructor of the Sound Class wants the path to an OGG, MOD/XM file. You should use one of these formats to make sure everythings works as expected.

Comment: "org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Could not locate OpenAL library." i found this from netbeans output. what is the meaning of this? what should i do?

Comment: Do you have the OpenAL natives on the library path?

Comment: yeah. they are located in the library path

Comment: Usually this exception gets thrown when you don't have OpenAL natives on your library path or you are not using the newest version of lwjgl.
I think you need atleast 2.5 or higher.